# VueJS (resource, router and @websanova/vue-auth) login with JWT tokens refresh token error

Tags: authentication, jwt, vue.js, vue-resource, vue-router

I'm building an app using VueJS and Electron, now I'm trying to create a login using the `@websanova/vue-auth` package and everything goes well (login, logout, route protection, etc..) the only thing I'm stuck on is that everytime I log in and refresh or restart electron, it kicks me back to the login page. The weird thing is, it refreshed the token successfully, if I look in the localstorage it is updated and when I try to make a manual request using a REST client the token works. I just can't get into the app using that token.

I'm using the latest versions of `VueJS`, `vue-router`, `vue-resource` and `@websanova/vue-auth` as of today (19-sep-2016).

The API side is a Laravel 5.3 installation and I'm using the `tymondesigns/jwt-auth` package to handle the JWT tokens.

this is how I use my routes:

```
'/': {
    auth: true,
    name: 'dashboard',
    component: HomeView
},
'/login': {
    auth: false,
    name: 'login',
    component: LoginView
}
```

The views are being compiled using browserify and vueify.

My login function is like this:

```
this.$auth.login({
    body: this.body,
    success: function () {
        this.loading = false;
    },
    error: function () {
        this.error.status = true;
        this.loading = false;
        this.body.password = '';
    },
    rememberMe: true
});
```

If you need more information in order to be able to help me, just let me know.

**Edit:** If you want to take a look, here are the links to the repo's:

API: https://github.com/luukhoeben/rmi-app-api

Electron app: https://github.com/luukhoeben/rmi-app-electron

Thanks,
Luuk

Comment: See if the `User` GET request that is done right after you enter the app is sent successfully. ATM i'm trying something similar but with a Hybrid app and 1 out of 5 times when my token gets refreshed (because the vue-auth package does this every time you start it) the immediate requests don't pass as they carry the old token.
If you override the `expiredToken` function in the `Options`, you could skip the refresh token thing.

Comment: Yes I get the user back, but the problem occurs when I refresh the page or restart the application. 

**Edit:** I think it is something else tho, because when I try to override the expiredToken function it still kicks me back to the login page when I refresh.

Answer (score 0):

If you set

```
Vue.use(Auth, {
   router: Router,
   http: Vue.$http,
   tokenExpired: () => {
     return false
   }
})
```

Setting `tokenExpired` to return false, like this, you will skip the token refresh all together, which is not that bad. Downside is that your clients will have an expired token at some point and will be forced to re-login.

Another method is to try and check when the token will expire and refresh based on that.

Comment: Aha, I can try that, but isn't there a logical explanation for this problem? Because I would love to have it fixed so it works like it should.

Comment: Well its an issue between the package and laravel-jwt. An easy fix is to stop the jwt blacklist on laravel, this way it won't reject your request immediately. Just add to your env variables `JWT_BLACKLIST_ENABLE = false `There is a new version on its way that has grace period that is supposed to fix this issue.

Comment: Yeah I've tried that aswell, but with no luck unfortunately :(

Comment: You should put it somewhere for someone to test, otherwise ee can't help much.

Comment: Will do, I'll update here when I've put it on github :)

Comment: I've put it on github, the links are: 
API: https://github.com/luukhoeben/rmi-app-api
Electron Client: https://github.com/luukhoeben/rmi-app-electron

Comment: @LuukHoeben Is your Auth example client and API resolved? I am looking for a complete working example.